# Should the Power Spectral Density be complex?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, noise

I need help!

I'm trying to calculate the Power Spectral Density of a quantum operator ($\delta \hat{n}(t)$) given by:

$$ \delta \hat{n}(t) = A(t)\delta\hat{a}(t)+A^{*}(t)\delta\hat{a}^{\dagger}(t) $$

$\delta\hat{a}(t)$ is a wide-sense stationary process and $A(t)$ is a complex time-dependent deterministic factor. To calculate the PSD ($S_{nn}(\omega)$) I'm employing the following definition:

$$ S_{nn}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau \overline{\langle \delta\hat{n}^{\dagger}(t+\tau)\delta\hat{n}(t)\rangle} e^{i \omega \tau}$$

where the bar indicates a time average. When calculating the autocorrelation I'm left with:

$$\langle \delta\hat{n}^{\dagger}(t+\tau)\delta\hat{n}(t)\rangle = A^{*}(t+\tau)A(t) \langle \delta\hat{a}^{\dagger}(t+\tau)\delta\hat{a}(t)\rangle + A(t+\tau)A^{∗}(t) \langle \delta\hat{a}(t+\tau)\delta\hat{a}^{\dagger}(t)\rangle+ A(t+\tau)A(t)\langle \delta\hat{a}(t+\tau)\delta\hat{a}(t)\rangle+ A(t+\tau)^{∗}A^{∗}(t)\langle \delta\hat{a}^{\dagger}(t+\tau)\delta\hat{a}^{\dagger}(t)\rangle$$

For reference, $A(t)=a_{0} + a_{1} e^{-i\delta t}$, where both $a_0$ and $a_1$ are complex. My problem arises when calculating the third and fourth terms on top. I expect the autocorrelation to be real (and hence the PSD), but calculating the time-average of the third and fourth terms of the autocorrelation gives:

$$\overline{A(t+\tau)A(t)} = (a_{0}^{*})^2$$

$$\overline{A(t+\tau)^{∗}A^{∗}(t)} = a_{0}^2$$

Therefore, the only way for the autocorrelation of $\delta\hat{n}(t)$ to be real is if $\langle \delta\hat{a}^{\dagger}(t+\tau)\delta\hat{a}^{\dagger}(t)\rangle$ and $\langle \delta\hat{a}(t+\tau)\delta\hat{a}(t)\rangle$ are both zero, but I don't see why. I'm trying to replicate the calculations made in this article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.6929v2 (eq. 32, pg.5).

So basically:

1. Should $\langle \delta\hat{a}^{\dagger}(t+\tau)\delta\hat{a}^{\dagger}(t)\rangle = \langle \delta\hat{a}(t+\tau)\delta\hat{a}(t)\rangle = 0$?
2. or is the something fundamentally wrong with my calculations?

Comment: Are these expectation values taken in the "vacuum"? Are the $a$'s the operators that diagonalize the Hamiltonian, or are they "pre-diagonal" operators in terms of which you'll write operators that diagonalize the Hamiltonian? Is the Hamiltonian particle-conserving?  Etc. The point, I think, is that whether or not those expectation values are zero or not depend on the specific system in question, the specific *state* in question, and the nature of those operators relative to the diagonalization procedure.

Comment: The $\delta \hat{a}(t)$ operator is a sum of thermal noise operators at T = 0, noise operators with the usual delta two-point correlation. Im trying to understand why in the article theses expectation values are zero.

Comment: @march $\delta \hat{a}(t)$ has both thermal noise operators and their hermitian conjugates. If $\delta \hat{a}$ didn't had both the noise operators and their h.c then it would be easy to see why the expectations would be zero at T=0.